# Releasing UIImage imageNamed

Tags: objective-c, iphone

When I use UIImage imagenamed: should I set the variables which hold UIImages to nil before exit? I notice that sometimes when I switch between views which have UIImages, the memory keeps growing and growing with each switch back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting variables to nil is not necessary.

Setting properties to nil (`self.property = nil;`) will release them if they're declared `@property (retain)`.

Since `+imageNamed:` doesn't start with "alloc", "copy", "new", or "retain", you don't have to release it. It's possible things are staying in memory because the space isn't needed. Are you seeing any leaks or just memory usage?

Comment: I start at ~340MB (no programs open). If I switch views back and forth my memory drops by about 9MB per switch. Every so often it recovers around 5MB, but I took it down to 190MB and waited and nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Setting UIImage variables to `nil` won't do anything particularly useful. Also, you shouldn't release the image returned from `+imageNamed:`, since the method name does not imply that you have ownership of the returned object.

Cocoa maintains an image cache. Subsequent calls to `imageNamed:` will return the same `UIImage` object if it is loaded already (since `UIImage` objects are immutable), otherwise it will load it again into the cache. The lifetime of the image in the cache is up to Cocoa to decide. In low-memory situations the image data may be purged. Even though the actual internal image data is purged from the cache, the object that you have is still able to reference the image (Cocoa will reload the image data if it was purged from the cache). It is explained throughout the [`UIImage` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If your memory usage is consistently growing then the leak is probably coming from somewhere else.